# django - add field to user profile admin form

Tags: python, django, admin, models

With the given screenshot, I want to add a select dropdown to the user add page from another model that already exists on the system. how do i do this?[image: django admin]

Here is my account/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from entities.models import Company
from entities.models import Venue

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'Test'
```

and here is my account/admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from entities.models import Company
from entities.models import Venue

class CompanyInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Company

class VenueInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Venue

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = [
        CompanyInline,
        VenueInline,
    ]

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

now when I add the above code and return to the user add page, I have this error:

[image: admin user add error]

The Company and Venue models are both populated with data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 3):

Arg, this happens every time I post something up. I give the code another look-through and find the problem.

Anyways, for the other unfortunates having the same problem, I just changed my account/admin.py to the following

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from account.models import UserProfile

class UserProfileInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = UserProfile

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = [
        UserProfileInline,
    ]

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

Comment: hey @mark I tried your solution but I stuck while `saving` data 
[please follow up my question for more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71855650/how-to-add-profile-fields-in-user-model-in-admin-area-of-django-and-save-data-ac
)

Comment: Sorry... but I haven't programmed in Django in a decade 